# R - Parameterized unzipping of file using system command

Tags: r, system, backslash

I was disappointed by the slow speed of unzipping a large file in R using:

```
unzip("C:/My File.zip", exdir="C:/")
```

so I wrote a system command instead:

```
system('powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path "C:/My File.zip" -DestinationPath "C:/" -Force"')
```

This command works beautifully but now that I want to parameterize the input file I have run into a problem with the backslash escape character when constructing the command:

```
in_file <- "C:/My File.zip"
command <- paste0("\'powershell -command \"Expand-Archive -Path \"", in_file, "\" -DestinationPath \"C:/\" -Force\"'")
```

Whilst `cat(command)` looks like the string I want:

```
cat(command)
> 'powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path "C:/My File.zip" -DestinationPath "C:/" -Force"'
```

When I run `system(command)` I get an error:

```
Warning message:
running command ''powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path "C:/My File.zip" -DestinationPath "C:/" -Force"'' had status 127
```

I put this down to the command not actually functioning like I want as the escape characters are still there:

```
print(command)
> "'powershell -command \"Expand-Archive -Path \"C:/My File.zip\" -DestinationPath \"C:/\" -Force\"'"
```

I have made all sorts of attempts to remove the backslashes e.g. `gsub("\","",str, fixed=TRUE)` but I just can't manage it.

How can I get my unzip command to work?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `\'` at the begining and at the end in `paste0` line? or thry this one:`command <- paste0('powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path "', in_file, '" -DestinationPath "C:/" -Force')`.

Comment: I missed a `"` after `-Force`. It should be `command <- paste0('powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path "', in_file, '" -DestinationPath "C:/" -Force"')`

Comment: Thanks for the revision, it works perfectly.

Comment: an explanation: You do not need the `'` at the begining or end in the string `command`.  the `'` in the `system` commond is the same as `"` and just indicates this is a string and  the contents within the quote is the actual system command to be executed.

Comment: An extension - if your path name contains spaces then you'll need to include the right number of quotes: paste0('powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path """', in_file, '""" -DestinationPath """', out_file, '""" -Force"')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*mt1022* got me on the right track. For the completion of this post, the answer is to use:

```
paste0('powershell -command "Expand-Archive -Path """', in_file, '""" -DestinationPath """', out_file, '""" -Force"')
```